# How to Extract a Tuple from an RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, tuples, rdd

I have a key-value pair rdd where the values are in the form of a tuple. I want to extract the values individually in tuple format which i later need to input somewhere else. The rdd is in the format as below

```
data = [('d2', (4.992657999999999, 1.9902080000000009)),
 ('d1', (2.993982000000001, 5.004130000000006)),
 ('d3', (2.0329879999999987, 1.0033780000000003))]
```

From this i am trying to extract (4.992657999999999, 1.9902080000000009), (2.993982000000001, 5.004130000000006) and (2.0329879999999987, 1.0033780000000003), all individually.

I have tried using the following code but i am getting stuck within an rdd and i am unable to use the output further.

```
data.values().take(1)

Out[89]: [(4.992657999999999, 1.9902080000000009)]
```

What am i doing wrong here? Will really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Why don't you try `data.values().collect()`?

Comment: But how can i extract each value individually with that?

Comment: that's just a list, you can access the values like `data_list = data.values().collect()` and `data_list[0]`